# Как экранировать тег script

Tags: javascript, html, django

Я использую в django шаблоне вот такой код:

```
<script>
    let email = '{{ current_user_email|escapejs }}';
    let currentUserID = {{ current_user_id|escapejs }};
</script>
```

Но когда я захожу в инспектор кода в браузере, видны переменные и их значения:

```
<script>
    let email = 'example@ex.com';
    let currentUserID = 1;
</script>
```

Это небезопасно. Можно ли как-то экранировать тег script или другим способом передавать переменные из шаблона в js.

Comment: Почему это не безопасно?

Comment: JS код как бы в браузере выполняется) соответственно все что в нем доступно юзеру, как бы вы не извращались) да и... если это мыло и айди пользователя, они и так ему известны.. в чем проблема)

Comment: И при передаче данных браузер все равно покажет, какие данные приходят :) Возможно вам стоит задуматься над тем, что бы юзеру выдавать некий токен, а на сервере уже по выданному токену вытаскивать данные, которые вы не хотите передавать клиенту

Comment: @SwaD собственно в Django уже есть sessionid

Comment: Просто таким способом, как в вопросе, я еще передаю электронную почту других пользователей и это меня насторожило, что в инспекторе кода видно значения переменных

Comment: @Leonid наверное, начать стоит с вопроса — зачем вообще вы передаёте в браузер почты других пользователей?

Comment: ну не совсем электронную почту, а путь к фото собеседника, а у меня путь такой: media/users/user_profile_images/<user_email>/<images>/ когда в инструментах разработчика во вкладке NetWork смотришь запросы к серверу, видно, что был послан запрос, чтобы получить фото собеседника

Comment: Тогда, наверно, продолжить стоит вопросом — зачем путь к фото содержит email?

Comment: а как мне сохранять фото пользователей? Хотя можно по ID пользователя, email использовался как уникальный идентификатор каждого пользователя

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147234/discussion-between-leonid-and-andreymal).